# GRUB2 password editing protect

Tags: grub2, encryption

If I protect GRUB2 with a password it will be written inside the grub2.cgf file.

If a potential user mounts the drive and changes it, it will be possible to change the root password and modify the system.

In detail, if you mount the disk in another machine and handly paste a GRUB2 password generated in another machine, next time you reboot, you can edit GRUB by using the new password.

Is there a way to protect it?
I've tried to use luks but I don't want to type a password every time I boot my system.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about protecting Grub2 bootloader from modifications with a password.

How to password protect the Grub2 bootloader:

First we generate an encrypted password.

```
  sudo grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2
```

We will get an output similar to the following:

```
  Enter password: 
  Enter password: 
  Reenter password: 
  Your PBKDF2 is grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.743275C021122091A9EF4602AB6EF14C22F8B7AC6C22A0A90C0283C0EBC8935E6AC255C49AD6FBC33FC063BBF7AB6A7A3523BBD78C20CCA94F6063CD201C5B03.8968F047042AE0C1264F7CB657601C0E95A1E55555C097954FBA18FAC80A1F30B06ADF651F9DC41F55C6EEA74440C11134440B0E3C84CDD5C5A2C7BA09D99995
```

Now it is necessary to edit the file: /etc/grub.d/00_header

```
  sudo nano /etc/grub.d/00_header
```

At the end of the file, the following lines must be placed, taking care that the username and password generated remain on a single line.

```
  cat << EOF
  set superusers="Giuseppe" 
  password_pbkdf2 Giuseppe grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.743275C021122091A9EF4602AB6EF14C22F8B7AC6C22A0A90C0283C0EBC8935E6AC255C49AD6FBC33FC063BBF7AB6A7A3523BBD78C20CCA94F6063CD201C5B03.8968F047042AE0C1264F7CB657601C0E95A1E55555C097954FBA18FAC80A1F30B06ADF651F9DC41F55C6EEA74440C11134440B0E3C84CDD5C5A2C7BA09D99995
  EOF
```

Now it is necessary to edit file /etc/grub.d/10_linux

```
  sudo nano /etc/grub.d/10_linux
```

In this file, you need to locate the linux-entry () function.

It is located approximately on line 64.

Inside this function approximately on (line 75 we place the printf command.

Inside this command it is necessary to introduce the --user option followed by the username placed in set superusers.

Once this is done in each menu that is generated, the --users option will be added, protecting all the entries to the different Kernels that are installed in the boot menu.

```
  linux_entry ()
  {
      os="$1"
      version="$2"
      type="$3"
      args="$4"
    -  
    -  
    -
      
     fi
     printf "menuentry '${title}' ${CLASS} {\n" "${os}" "${version}"
     cat << EOF   
     recordfail
```

Modified line

```
     printf "menuentry --users Giuseppe'${title}' ${CLASS} {\n" "${os}" "${version}"
```

Finally, you only need to update Grub2 for the changes to take effect.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I already do this but let's imagine a user disconnects the hard drive, connects to another one, and paste a freshly new generated password that overwrites mine, there isn't a way to avoid this kind of behavior?

Comment: encrypting the drive will possibly help prevent any modification of files @GiuseppePrometeo

Comment: I imagined that. Thank you!